# RxJava: Merging Observable with Completable does not work

Tags: java, concurrency, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have an Observable that at some point has to write things to the cache - and we would like to wait that writes are done before finishing the whole operation on the observable (for reporting purposes).

For the purpose of test, the cache write Completable looks like this:

```
   Completable.create(
                  emitter ->
                      new Thread(
                              () -> {
                                try {
                                  Thread.sleep(2000);
                                  doSomething();
                                  emitter.onComplete();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                              })
                          .start());
```

Since I have several cache writes, I try to merge them in a container class:

```
public class CacheInsertionResultsTracker {

  private Completable cacheInsertResultsCompletable;

  public CacheInsertionResultsTracker() {
    this.cacheInsertResultsCompletable = Completable.complete();
  }

  public synchronized void add(Completable cacheInsertResult) {
    this.cacheInsertResultsCompletable = this.cacheInsertResultsCompletable.mergeWith(cacheInsertResult);
  }

  public Completable getCompletable() {
    return this.cacheInsertResultsCompletable;
  }
}
```

And I try to merge it with Observable in a following way:

```
CacheInsertionResultsTracker tracker = new ...;
    observable
        .doOnNext(next->tracker.add(next.writeToCache(...)))
        .mergeWith(Completable.defer(()->tracker.getCompletable()))
        .subscribe(
            // on next
            this::logNextElement
            // on error
            this::finishWithError
            // on complete
            this::finishWithSuccess
            );
```

How could I make sure that by the time finishWithSuccess is called the doSomething is completed?
The problem is that the Completable reference is updated every time I add a new one, and it happens after the mergeWith runs...

Comment: Is this in an unit test? If you don't wait for the sequence to complete while still in the test method, you may never see the outcome. For example, [this](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/a88d2d6c46433302498412e6c1a605fe) code won't print done if run as a JUnit test but prints properly when run as a program. Enable the thread.sleep in the test and see what happens.

Comment: I edited the question to add more details. It seems that the problem is actually not the mergeWith method per se, but the fact that I update the Completable after mergeWith takes it. If instead of merge, I just subscribe to this Completable in the finishWithSuccess method, it works, but it is kind of ugly...

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve here with that mutable cache. You say you add more `Completable`s while the `observable` is already running. How would the sequence now you stopped adding more `Completable`s so it can complete the observable and call `finishWithSuccess`?

Comment: Well, that's true. Is there an elegant alternative for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that seems to work for our use case is to use concatWith + defer:

```
observable
    .doOnNext(next->tracker.add(next.writeToCache(...)))
    .concatWith(Completable.defer(()->tracker.getCompletable()))
    .subscribe(
        // on next
        this::logNextElement
        // on error
        this::finishWithError
        // on complete
        this::finishWithSuccess
        );
```

Concat assures that the subscription to the Completable happens only after the Observable is done, and defer defers getting the final Completable till this subscription (so all the objects are already added to the tracker).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you could replace the completable cache with `ReplaySubject<Completable>`, do some timeout to detect inactivity and have the observable sequence end.

```java
 ReplaySubject<Completable> cache = ReplaySubject.create();

 cache.onNext(completable);

 observable.mergeWith(
     cache.flatMapCompletable(v -> v)
          .timeout(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Completable.complete())
 )
```

**Edit:**

Your updated example implies you want to run `Completable`s in response to items in the main `observable`, isolated to that sequence, and wait for all of them to complete. This is a typical use case for `flatMap`:

```java
  observable.flatMap(
       next -> next.writeToCache(...).andThen(Observable.just(next))
  )
  .subscribe(
        this::logNextElement
        // on error
        this::finishWithError
        // on complete
        this::finishWithSuccess
   );
```